# Shared pointer with deleter

Tags: c++, pointers

I tried to use the shared_ptr with deleter:

```
class A{ };

void (*foo)(){ };

int main(){
    std::shared_ptr<A> sp(new A, foo); //error: too many arguments to function call, 
                                       //expected 0, have 1
}
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Your `deleter function` should take `A*` as type, for example look at below Deleter implementation:

```
struct A{ };

void Deleter(A* p){ delete p; };

int main(){
    std::shared_ptr<A> sp(new A, Deleter); 
    return 0;
}
```

Also, you only declared function pointer `foo`, you need to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Your custom deleter is not implemented correctly.  Try this instead:

```
void foo(A* p)
{
    // do something, or not, it is up to you...
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> sp(new A, foo);
}
```

https://ideone.com/DHGpMy

Comment: @stella: Your implementation is still wrong. Look again at what I actually wrote. There is a big difference between `void foo(A*) {}` and `void (*foo)(A*) {}`.  You are declaring a *pointer to a function* but not assigning any function for it to point at. That is why you get a segfault. Get rid of the `(*)` portion so it is an actual function.

Answer (score 0):

you can consider that
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr/

std::shared_ptr p4 (new int, std::default_delete());

std::shared_ptr p5 (new int, [](int* p){delete p;}, std::allocator());